# Looking for a Direct Attached Storage solution

Tags: data-storage

I'm looking for a Direct Attached Storage solution that can accept a minimum of 12x SATA 2.5in HDDs and can connect to the host raid controller's sff-8088 port. I'm not looking for actual listings or compatibility from here, I just need a model that I can look for myself. If you happen to know for some crazy reason that it is compatible with an IBM x3650 please do come forwards, but don't go looking for that stuff. I'll be back if I find one myself.

Thanks for your time.